# Loading different Shared libraries c++

Tags: c++11, object, shared-libraries, dynamic-library, cloning

I am a beginner in Using Shared Libraries. I kind of need some direction how to go about solving an issue. I want to load different *.so files and load them and store the resultant initialized objects of the file in a vector.

My idea was that : call the function which loads the library and initializes the functions in the library which are a part of a class. So all this info are a part of an object of that class. Then we clone this object into another object and store in a vector of classes. Then close this library and load another one and repeat the same process.

I had two doubts based the idea :

1. Will this method of loading diff libraries preserve the content of different objects initalized and act independently ?
2. IF idea looks good , what could be the best way to clone the object here ?

Would be highly obliged if someone could please give me a heads-up here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an automatic registration of "classes" (or more accurately, of factories) loaded from .so files, you can rely on a global constructor to be called in each .so that would do a "factory registration" upon the .so load.

### This idea is called "Runtime Class Registration"

Suppose the .so files represent algorithms that we want to register, so the program will hold all algorithms that were defined in all the .so files.

In each .so there shall be one .cpp file that will do the following:

```
REGISTER_ALGORITHM (<Algorithm_Class_Name>)
```

for example:

```
REGISTER_ALGORITHM (BfsAlgorithm)
```

The REGISTER_ALGORITHM would be a macro with the following implementation:

```
#define REGISTER_ALGORITHM(class_name) \
    AlgorithmRegistration register_me_##class_name \
        ([]{return make_unique<class_name>();}, #class_name);
```

And AlgorithmRegistration would be a class with the following implementation:

```
struct AlgorithmRegistration {
    AlgorithmRegistration(function<unique_ptr<AbstractAlgorithm>()>, string name);
};

AlgorithmRegistration::AlgorithmRegistration(std::function<unique_ptr<AbstractAlgorithm>()> algorithmFactory, string name) {
    AlgorithmRegistrar::getInstance().registerAlgorithm(algorithmFactory, name);
}
```

The AlgorithmRegistrar would be a Singleton that actually manages the container of all registered algorithms, e.g.:

```
class AlgorithmRegistrar {
    list<std::string> algorithmNames;
    list<std::function<unique_ptr<AbstractAlgorithm>()>> algorithmFactories;
    void registerAlgorithm(std::function<unique_ptr<AbstractAlgorithm>()> algorithmFactory, const string& name) {
        algorithmFactories.push_back(algorithmFactory);
        algorithmNames.push_back(name);
    }
public:
    friend struct AlgorithmRegistration;
    list<unique_ptr<AbstractAlgorithm>> getAlgorithms()const {
        list<unique_ptr<AbstractAlgorithm>> algorithms;
        for(auto algorithmFactoryFunc : algorithmFactories) {
            algorithms.push_back(algorithmFactoryFunc());
        }
        return algorithms;
    }
    const list<std::string>& getAlgorithmNames()const {
        return algorithmNames;
    }
    size_t size()const {
        return algorithmFactories.size();
    }
    static AlgorithmRegistrar& getInstance() {
        static AlgorithmRegistrar instance;
        return instance;
    }
};
```

Now you can have a main:

```
//========================================================================
// M A I N
//========================================================================
int main() {

    // get the AlgorithmRegistrar singleton
    AlgorithmRegistrar& registrar = AlgorithmRegistrar::getInstance();

    if(registrar.size() == 0) {
        // TODO: no algorithms loaded - print usage etc.
    }

    // get new instances of the algorithms and run them
    auto algorithms = registrar.getAlgorithms();
    auto& algorithmNames = registrar.getAlgorithmNames();
    auto pName = algorithmNames.begin();
    for(auto& algorithm: algorithms) {
        cout << *(pName++) << ": " << algorithm->sayHello() << endl;
    }

}
//========================================================================
```

(The code above doesn't show the actual load of the .so files which shall be done with dlopen and closed later with dlclose. Note that due to the automatic registration there is no need to use dlsym).

Code example for the factory registration: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/283feaa9ffb62dd1